# WebRequest или WebClient работают в console app и не работают в UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, webclient

Мне необходимо получить json от https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js к примеру при нажатии на кнопку в UWP.
В console app у меня это получается сделать к примеру с помощью WebClient:

```
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
               Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js");
               var json = wc.DownloadString(uri);
               Console.WriteLine(json);
            }
```

Или WebRequest:

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            response.Close();
```

Когда я добавляю этот код в UWP проект получаю [image: Сообщение об ошибке]

```
Вызвано исключение: "System.Exception" в System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Сведения WinRT: Не удается найти сервер с таким именем или адресом

Вызвано исключение: "System.Exception" в System.Net.Http.dll
Сведения WinRT: Не удается найти сервер с таким именем или адресом

Вызвано исключение: "System.Exception" в System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Сведения WinRT: Не удается найти сервер с таким именем или адресом

"CurrencyConverter.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Загружено "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.29301.2_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll". 
Вызвано исключение: "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException" в System.Net.Http.dll
Вызвано исключение: "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException" в System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Вызвано исключение: "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException" в System.Net.Http.dll
Вызвано исключение: "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException" в System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Вызвано исключение: "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException" в System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: У приложения скорее всего разрешения на доступ в интернет нет. И лучше используйте `HttpClient`, чем устаревшие 2 варианта, которые вы показали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да у приложения не было доступа к интернету, всё из-за UWP. Разрешение даётся в манифесте.

Comment: Было бы полезно, если бы вы показали, как оно в манифесте выглядит и дали ссылку на документацию.